# Android Disable past dates in datepicker

Tags: android

I need to disable past dates in datepicker control. This control is opened in a dialog box, there I want to disable past dates so that it throws error if past date is picked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you are using [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) and the [OnDateSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html) that you have to pass to the constructor doesn't fit your needs because you have to throw the error **before** the date is actually set.

In this case you can extend DatePickerDialog and make your own implementation of [OnDateChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#onDateChanged%28android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), which is called everytime that the date changes and you get as parameters the DatePicker, and the new year, month and day values, so you can check if that date is past and in that case throw the error (with a Toast or whatever) and call [DatePicker.updateDate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29) to set a correct value (so that DatePicker is allways in a consistent state).

Also, you can call to `DatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, onDateChangedListener);` then you can pass a `onDateChangedListener` implementation without having to extend DatePickerDialog

Answer (score 1):

You can check date manually.. And restrict user from enter invalid date:

Check following code snippet:

```
     if((futureDate.getDate() == currentDate1.getDate() && futureDate.getMonth()== currentDate1.getMonth() && futureDate.getYear() == currentDate1.getYear()))
              {
                  if(futureDate.after(currentDate1))
                  {
                                   // Accept Date
                  }
                  else
                  {
                                  // Alert user Date is Invalid
                  }

              }
              else
              {
                         // Alert user Date is Invalid
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running API 11 or more, use the [setMinDate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) method on `DatePicker`.  This hides all dates before the specified date.

Comment: So doesn't the setMinDate() just grey out the past dates on the DatePicker?  But the user can still select a past date.  Is there a way to actually disable the selection of a past date?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

public void openDateDialog(View view) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int dayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int monthOfYear = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

```
new MyDatePickerDialog(view.getContext(), null, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).show();;
```

}

```
 class MyDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {


        public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
                int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            this.context = context;
        }


        private Context context;



        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
              Calendar dareSelected = Calendar.getInstance();
                dareSelected.set(year, month, day);
                Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

               int a = dareSelected.compareTo(currentDate);
               if(a<0){
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }else{
                   setDate(year,month,day);
               }
        }
    }

    private void setDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
        tvText.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(dayOfMonth))
                .append("-").append(pad(monthOfYear + 1)).append("-")
                .append(pad(year)));

    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
```