# How to disable dates before today date in DatePickerDialog Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker

I want to disable the dates before today date in the DatePickerDialog .I am new in android please suggest me how could i do this .Here is my code that i have written for DatePickerDialog

```
 final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateLabel(val);
            }
        };
        depart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DatePickerDialog(this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                    val=1;
                }
            });

        returnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new DatePickerDialog(this, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                            val=2;
                }
            });


private void updateLabel(int val) {

        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        Log.d("Date vlue ", "==="+sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        if(val==1)
            depart.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        else
            returnDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        }
```

Please suggest me what have to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625002/android-disable-past-dates-in-datepicker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this example..!

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvDisplayDate;

    private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int myear;
    private int mmonth;
    private int mday;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    // display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);       

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(mmonth + 1).append("-").append(mday).append("-")
                .append(myear).append(" "));
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, myear,mmonth,
                    mday){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                    if (year < myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            myear = selectedYear;
            mmonth = selectedMonth;
            mday = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mmonth + 1)
                    .append("-").append(mday).append("-").append(myear)
                    .append(" "));    

        }
    };

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current Date (M-D-YYYY): "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: disable dates before today date in DatePickerDialog.

Comment: I tried this it is allowing only to pick dates before today dates

Comment: I it is working now how could i implement this in my code because i have two calenders on my page

Comment: inside onclick listener write this line showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); and add Dialog onCreateDialog() function...

Comment: Now it is working fine now the issue is that once user selects a date after that he can't select the date before that selected date

Comment: @Hari i want to show only 1 year calender from todays date.how we can do that

Comment: `Hariharan` Your code is working fine, but it doesn't seem to work when i install it on my phone. I mean previous dates are getting selected, which shouldn't happen right? How do i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Get the DatePicker used in your DatePickerDialog with the getDatePicker() method and use the [setMinDate(Long millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29) method.

Pass to it the minimum date (in milliseconds from Epoch) you have to set.

So you can do something like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
DatePicker datePicker = date.getDatePicker();
datePicker.setMinDate(d.getTime());
```

---

**EDIT:**

ok, so when your creating your DatePickerDialog, before showing it, just save it to a variable, set the minimum date and then show it.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(IweenFlightSearch.this, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse("21/12/2012");
dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(d.getTime());
dpd.show();
```

this should work.

Comment: i didn't got u where i have to make these changes so that the date before today will be disabled

Comment: You haven't post all your code, so it's hard to say "where" you have to make the changes. You should have somewhere a DatePickerDialog or a DatePicker. If you want further help you should show us where you're using those classes.

Comment: Please see in my question i have posted my complete code that i am using for datePickerDailog

Comment: I like this one a lot better than the accepted answer.  Very clean and simple.

Answer (score 6):

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,year,month,day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return datePickerDialog;
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it is too late. But hope this will helps. Use

```
date .getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

in your case date is DatePickerDialog

Cheers!

Comment: Could you please explain the need of that minus 1000

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Probably the -1000 is because you get the current time in milliseconds

Comment: Most likely because of this IllegalArgumentException issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution .hope it will help to someone
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

```
depart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

                }
            });



protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(this, date,myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                    if (year < now.get(Calendar.YEAR))

                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (monthOfYear < now.get(Calendar.MONTH) && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (dayOfMonth < now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR) && 
                            monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                        }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }
```