# Restrict DatePicker entries in Android

Tags: android, validation, datepicker, datetimepicker

I want to restrict datepicker entries based on FROM and TO date. The code below works just fine but in UI the disabled dates can be selected when it should be disabled and non clickable.

Here is the code :

```
if (v == fromDateButton || v == toDateButton) {
            final Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            mYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            String day = "", month = "";

                            monthOfYear = (monthOfYear + 1); // Calendar returns 1st month as 0

                            if (monthOfYear <= 9)
                                month = "0" + monthOfYear;
                            else month = monthOfYear + "";

                            if (dayOfMonth <= 9)
                                day = "0" + (dayOfMonth);
                            else day = (dayOfMonth) + "";

                            if (v == fromDateButton)
                                fromDateField.setText(day + "/"
                                        + month + "/" + year);

                            else toDateField.setText(day + "/"
                                    + month + "/" + year);


                            // Enable todate field
                            toDateButton.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

            if (!toDateButton.isEnabled()) {
                dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            }

            if (v == toDateButton) {
                // if (fromDateField.getText() != null && fromDateField.getText() != "") {

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date;
                try {
                    date = df.parse(fromDateField.getText().toString());
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(date.getTime());
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // }

            }

            if (v == fromDateButton) {
                // if (toDateField.getText() != null && toDateField.getText() != "") {

                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                Date date;
                try {
                    date = df.parse(toDateField.getText().toString());
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(date.getTime());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // }
            }

            dpd.show();
        }
```

And here is the picker from which a disabled field can be selected

[image]

Any idea why it's happening ? I just need to restrict user from selecting disabled dates.

Comment: Check this out may be it resolve your problem too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857310/how-to-block-only-past-dates-in-datepicker-in-android

Comment: Well the validation par is working but I don't know why disabled dates can also be selected by tapping on them.