# datePickerDialog how to set the shown dates?

Tags: android

I am using a [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) as shown below.
I want to limit the dates shown so the user can't pick a date after today, but can pick any date in the past. How do I do this?

```
 final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            mMissedStampDate = new DateTime().withDate(i, i1, i2);
            textView.setText(mMissedStampDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
    };

    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, onDateSetListener, mMissedStampDate.getYear(), mMissedStampDate.getMonthOfYear(), mMissedStampDate.getDayOfMonth());

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878751/how-to-disable-dates-before-today-date-in-datepickerdialog-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        mMissedStampDate = new DateTime().withDate(i, i1, i2);
        textView.setText(mMissedStampDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
};

final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, onDateSetListener, mMissedStampDate.getYear(), mMissedStampDate.getMonthOfYear(), mMissedStampDate.getDayOfMonth());

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Use [setMinDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)) & [setMaxDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate(long))

Official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Answer (score 1):

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

From `DatePickerDialog` with `getDatePicker()` method. Set the `max date` to `current date` with `setMaxDate()`.

```
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```